# Best permutation count algorithm in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, binary, permutation

I am trying to count the number of numbers that are expressed by P number of 1's and 0's in binary form. If P = 2, then the numbers expressed are 0011, 1100, 0110, 0101, 1001, 1010, so the count is 6.

I tried:

```
[0,0,1,1].permutation.to_a.uniq
```

But it is not the best solution for big numbers (P can be <= 30).

What could be the best permutation technique, or do we have any straight forward math to do this?

Comment: How is decimal relevant to your issue? It does not look like it is.

Comment: How is the fact that P can be equal to or less than 30 affect the calculation for getting large numbers? Is not that severe when P becomes large?

Comment: @sawa the other part of the question involves a decimal limit A, B. 
E.g. we need to print the count based on a given range A,B. E.g. for the same example A=5,B=10,P=2 then I have only 4 values in this range (except 3 & 12)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Number of permutation can be calculated using factorial.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Other_uses_of_the_term_permutation)

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1]
(1..a.size).inject(:*)  # => 4! => 24
```

to count duplicated item, you need to divide above with 2! and 2! (2 => number of 0s, 1s)

---

=>  `4! / (2! * 2!)` => 6

```
class Fixnum
  def factorial
    (1..self).inject(:*)
  end
end

a.size.factorial / a.group_by(&:itself).map { |k, v| v.size.factorial }.inject(:*)
=> 6
```

---

For the given `p`, there's `(p*2)!` permutations / and should be divided by `(p! * p!)` to remove duplication:

```
p = 2
(p*2).factorial / (p.factorial ** 2)                                               
# => 6
```

Comment: Combinatorics-challenged readers: for p=3 imagine the 1's (0's) to be black (white) blocks numbered 1, 2 and 3. The 6 blocks can be ordered 6! ways. Now consider any one of those 6! orderings (e.g., w3, b1, b3, w1, w2, b2). If we only care about the ordering of colors, we can ask how many ways the black blocks in this sequence can be reordered. There are 3 ways to choose the first block and for each of those there are two ways to order the other two black blocks. Hence, there are 3! = 6 color-preserving orderings of black blocks...

Comment: ...For each of those orderings there are 3! color-preserving orderings of white blocks. Hence, for the given sequence of 6 blocks, there are 3!*3! color-preserving orderings of the blocks, which is why falsetru divided (2p)! by p!*p! to obtain the desired number of permutations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thanks for the kind explanation!

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer @CarySwoveland & falsetru

Comment: @falsetru what if we need to print the count based on a given range A,B. E.g. for the same example A=5,B=10,P=2 then I have only 4 values in this range (except 3 & 12)

Comment: @Yusuf, I don't have an idea for that except enumerating all permutations. How about post a separated question so that other people can answer?

Comment: @falsetru yes I would do that. Again thanks for your help on sharing your knowledge.